# how to make parameter from db context to use it in function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wrote some code to navigate to next record and it working well but I can't make it function to use it in all forms.

How can I make  parameter from dbcontext and using it with that code

```
var query = db.DefCities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.City_ID > pk);
b.DataSource = query;
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you trying to achieve(pseudo code maybe)?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: i i wrote that code for move to next next record but i have 20 forms i wan't to make this code in function and using this function in all forms notrepeating this code again and again but i can't make paraneter fron dbcontext
like follwing code but in now working

 public void NextRecord( DbContext bb, int Pk , int column, BindingSource b)
        {

        

            var  query   = (from cmd in bb
                     where cmd.City_ID  < Pk
                     orderby cmd.City_ID descending
                       select cmd).FirstOrDefault();



        }